# Double Quotes Formatting Issue in Rendered HTML Template - Python FastAPI

Tags: python, html, jinja2, fastapi

I'm encountering a formatting issue with double quotes in a rendered HTML template within a Python FastAPI microservice. The HTML template is stored in a folder called "templates" and includes variables in the {{}} expression, which are replaced by Python code. The goal is to render this template and return it as an HTML string.

However, when the HTML is returned, the formatting is not as expected. The HTML contains double quotes with backslashes, causing spacing problems. I've shared a simplified example of the problem below:

**Returned HTML with "\:**

```
<span class=\"text_base text-9\">+34 642521273</span>
                </p>
<p class=\"spacer\"></p>\n
<!-- ... (more HTML) ... -->
```

**Python Code:**

```
async def __create_file__(
        self,
        input: InputData,
        contract_adapted,
        event_contract,
        draft: bool,
    ):
        env_template = Environment(
            loader=FileSystemLoader("/"),
            enable_async=True,
        )

        template = env_template.get_template(os.getenv(contract_adapted.template))
        render_template = await template.render_async(contract_adapted.data)

        pdf_task = asyncio.create_task(
            self.create_pdf(input, contract_adapted, event_contract, render_template)
        )

        if draft:
            render_template = render_template.replace('\\"', '"').replace("\\n", "")

            with open(
                os.getenv(contract_adapted.styles), "r", encoding="utf-8"
            ) as css_file:
                css_content = css_file.read().replace("\n", "")

            render_template_with_style = (
                f"<style>{css_content}</style>{render_template}"
            )

            return render_template_with_style

        await pdf_task
        return pdf_task.result()
```

**Problem:**

When the HTML is returned in draft mode, it is poorly formatted due to double quotes being escaped with backslashes.

**Desired Outcome:**

I want to return a well-formatted HTML string without the additional backslashes before double quotes.